# Converting sorted link list to binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I was trying to implement an algorithm to convert a sorted link list to BST but I am not getting the desired output.

Here is my function

```
public TreeNode linkListToBST(NodeList list) {
    TreeNode root = linkListToBSTrec(list.getHead(), list.count(list.getHead()));
    return root;
}

public TreeNode linkListToBSTrec(Node head, int n) {
    if (n <= 0) /* base case */
        return null;
    else {
        /* Recursively construct the left subtree */
        TreeNode left = linkListToBSTrec(head, n / 2);
        /*
         * Allocate memory for root, and link the above constructed left
         * subtree with root
         */
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(head.getData());
        root.setLeft(left);
        head = head.getNext(); /*
                                 * Change head pointer of Linked List for
                                 * parent recursive calls
                                 */
        /*
         * Recursively construct the right subtree and link it with root The
         * number of nodes in right subtree is total nodes - nodes in left
         * subtree - 1 (for root) which is n-n/2-1
         */
        root.setRight(linkListToBSTrec(head, n - (n / 2) - 1));

        return root;
    }
}
```

Calling snippet:

```
TreeNode root = bst.linkListToBST(list);
```

**Input list**: 1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8

**Output of level order traversal**:1->1->2->1->2->2->3->

Any help or answers will be very helpful :)

Algorithm source: [Link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-linked-list-to-balanced-bst/)

[Link to source code](http://ideone.com/3FwWnT)

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/leetcode-convert-sorted-list-to-binary-search-tree-java/ ?

Comment: Yup, I have implemented the solution for this using mid pointer.

Comment: The problem is `head = head.getNext()`. At the first level of recursion, that advances from `1` to `2`, when you really need to jump to `6`. BTW, you should really learn how to use a debugger: stepping through the code should make the problem obvious.

Comment: @user3386109 I think dont really need to jump to 5(beacuse I am not implementing it using a mid pointer). I am building the BST using bottom up approach.

Comment: Ok, step through the code with a debugger and see if you are correct.

Comment: Here's the link of the algorithm( method 2) ,maybe this can help
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-linked-list-to-balanced-bst/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are changing head pointer at a wrong point. It should be before TreeNode left = linkListToBSTrec(head, n / 2);

For the first time, your head and left both are 1. That's why you are getting the same data multiple times.

I haven't actually run the program. By looking at it I think head pointer should be changed earlier.

Comment: It wont help ,also during during first time , head=1 but left will be equal to null (leaf node) as left will be called until n>=0.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, your code does not express your intent.

I am not familiar with Java, but you would want to pass a reference to the node in the function linkListToBSTrec, otherwise the changed value of **head** from the left recursive call will not be reflected in the parent function.

Comment: I have added a link where this method is implemented in C .Maybe you can have a look and compare where I missed.

Comment: Yes, I had checked that link. But, I know only C++. I have no idea of Java, so you need to figure out how to pass reference to a reference as a function parameter.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to construct a *balanced* BST from a sorted list is to use the head of the tree as the *middle* element of the sorted list. Then the left subtree can be constructed recursively for the elements to the left of the middle element and similarly the right subtree contains elements to the right of the middle element.

You are using the leftmost element as the root which is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: I am considering a different algorithm, here's the link to the algorithm( method 2) geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-linked-list-to-balanced-bst